How important is storytelling when submitting a grant application (or even a science paper)?
A recent paper titled “Elements of Successful NIH Grant Applications” https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.2315735121 argued that telling a story is key to communicating science especially when submitting a grant application for funding but also when communicating science more generally. Most commentators on the paper strongly agreed. Intriguingly, a few, just as strongly, disagreed. They argued that science is different. Science does not tell stories. It strictly reports observations. Period.
What are the pros and cons of storytelling? Under what circumstances is storytelling a good idea?

"Science does not tell stories. It strictly reports observations. Period." is not correct, science is a pursuit of the best explanation for the observations.  It is about understanding which requires a logical progression of ideas and evaluation against the observations.  That doesn't need a story, but that view of science seems a pretty wrong-headed caricature to me.

Well, once a upon a time, there was a young bright-eyed academic who was about to submit a grant application...

Ironically I don't think the linked paper is a great example of how to use storytelling when communicating science.

This sounds like a question given as an assignment in class. Is it?

@einpoklum ... then they encountered the Land of the Storytellers who told stories about the Land of the Storynontellers who did not tell stories about the Storytellers. And so the young academic learnt a lot about both lands, before they met the powerful Project Magic Officer who explained to them that all they knew was only partial knowledge and they had to find the Magic in themselves. And so, the young academic, enwisened, returned home and happily (or unhappily) wrote grant proposals ever after.

It is not possible to effectively communicate observations without a story. Nobody but the most experienced experts in a field will be able to understand why you did an experiment, and what the data you report mean. It is necessary to tell a story around it that makes it possible for others to understand the context and implications of your observations. It is also necessary to tell a story because -- at least in my view -- papers are also tools to teach others what you have found out, and teaching is not effective if all you do is provide facts.
I will note that I have occasionally come across papers that only present facts in some areas of pure mathematics. These papers generally have very little in terms of introduction, then present the statement of some abstract theorem, and then the proof. Technically, of course, these papers succeed in extending humanity's knowledge, but I have always found that these papers are also elitist because their audience is so small -- very few people who do not have a deep background in a field will be able to understand the point of such papers. What these papers are missing in my opinion is a story.

@DikranMarsupial It's possible that what you call "logical progression of ideas" is what Wolfgang calls "story"

@DikranMarsupial I think that the thing you are describing is what people mean when they say "tell a story". When my supervisors give me feedback on making sure my writing "tells a story", they mean that they want me to present a logical progression of ideas so that each new section makes sense in context of the previous section. E.g. the introduction sets up the ideas necessary so that when I get to the methods, it seems obvious that I chose the methods I did because they follow naturally from the introduction.

@DikranMarsupial It’s a story, not necessarily the story of how you discovered the thing back in the days. A story doesn’t necessarily follow the original chronological or spatial or other order of its underlying events. Stories may have chronological sequences, but they may also have backstory introductions, interludes, callbacks, and many other devices that help the reader digest the raw information underlying it.

@DikranMarsupial I recommend to watch "Memento", but there are tons of stories out there that deliberately ignore or invert the original chronological order.

@DikranMarsupial When I was taught measure theory many years ago, it definitely felt like a story. It was still just a sequence of definitions, theorems and proofs, but the sequence made sense, I could tell that someone had very deliberately and purposefully chosen the order in which to present everything. It felt like we were going somewhere, building something. Years later I still remember it well. Conversely, I've attended an organic chemistry class which consisted in a structure-less list of molecules and their properties. There was no story there, and I've forgotten everything about it.

@DikranMarsupial I think you use the word "story" in a more literal/literary sense that I intend. I think of "story" here as "providing context and understanding to facts". Well written proofs of mathematical theorems often are stories, for example they could read as "In order to prove our assertion, we first tried to use the approach by Smith et al., but it turns out that we could not show the key step because our function spaces are only nearly convex, and one gets stuck in step X. As a consequence, ..." A non-story would be to just move symbols from the left to the right of the = sign.

I would just add here that the originally cited paper is about Science - that is about finding out about the world via empiricism. Pure maths is not empirical - it is purely reasoned. For that reason, i'm not sure that what works for Science and what works for Maths will be the same thing.

@IanSudbery I disagree. A paper that only states a theorem + proof, without any further explanation, is like publishing only a table of temperatures measured at a specific position over time. There is of course value in both, but only the most experienced readers will be able to put the information into context and understand its value (or lack thereof). It's an isolated piece of information. The "story" is doing readers the favor of putting the information in context of other pieces of information.

@wolfgangbangerth this is probably a disciplinary  difference,  but a paper which was only a table of temperatures would never be published in my field. There are data repositories where they could be made available to those that find them useful,  but it wouldn't justify a paper/article. The most common reason a paper/ grant is rejected is "there was no hypothesis". The second most common is " this is purely phenomological and not sufficiently mechanistic" - by which people mean the paper doesn't explain something that was previously unexplained.

@IanSudbery You misunderstand what I was trying to say. I'm saying that a paper that only contains a theorem + its proof should also not be publishable, for precisely the same reason. It doesn't state why anyone should care, because it doesn't embed the facts in their broader context. Only experts will be able to see the context that explains why the information given is relevant and important, and that is no different for theorem+proof than it is for publishing a temperature record.

@WolfgangBangerth, oh, I see. Sorry about that.

I believe at its source most of the disagreement you observe comes from a disagreement about terminology / word choices. The word "storytelling" rubs some scientists the wrong way, as it (to some) comes with a connotation of twisting and suppressing data to fit a specific narrative (or outright making things up - lying). Another word that is often used in a similar context, but just as controversial, is "selling" one's result.
This is not what most scientists mean when they say that storytelling is important to get grants or publications accepted.
What people mean is:

That you need to advocate why your proposed experiment or results are meaningful to a larger question (e.g., in your field of study or society in general). One can propose an infinite number of rigorous scientific studies, why should yours be prioritised over the studies proposed by others? Why should your results be presented in a high-profile conference?
That it is your responsibility as a scientist and author to communicate why people should care about your planned work or existing results.
That it is your responsibility to make it easy for people to understand not only your planned study or results, but also the importance of them. This is most easily done through "stories" (not fairy tales - just clear interpretations of what you plan to find or have found, what they mean, what impact this could have, etc.).

None of these items is particularly controversial, at least in my corner of science. It is widely accepted that a section that discusses potential impact is a natural element of a grant proposal, just as a discussion of results (as opposed to purely presenting results, for example in a table) is a natural element of papers. Even people who disagree strongly with the idea of "storytelling" in science still agree that these sections are important.

TL;DR Science is not a set of facts about the world, it is a process for discovering facts about the world. The best way to write about a process is to tell a story. In fact, that is all a story is.
Even more than a paper, grant writing is an act of persuasion. There are several things you must persuade the reader of: that you can carry out the proposed work, that the proposed work,  if carried out will answer the research question and that the research question is an interesting and valuable question to answer.  This last point is by far the most important thing in a grant proposal.  You must interest and excite the reviewer.  Dull and worthy just isn't going to cut it when only 10% of applications are successful, and panel members have a large stack of grants to read and discuss. More than 10% of grants are feasible. Thus the "story" becomes important for convincing people that the research you want to do is more important than all the other possible research.
But actually the same also applies in science. In science, we don't just collect data willy-nilly, but we capture data to either generate an hypothesis for an unexplained phenomenon, or to test an hypothesis. You must first convince the reader that your research problem is interesting. You must lead your reader through the idea that your hypothesis is reasonable, and then convince them that the decisions you made over how to test that the hypothesis are reasonable. Only then can you present your results.
Linguistics is the study of language - words. But just presenting a dictionary does not make you an expert linguist.

My other answer focused on the need to tell a story to succeed in the competitive aspect of science. But there is another reason.
In my supervision of students, the most consequential discriminator between them is whether they deeply understand why they’re doing what they’re doing. If they don’t understand what led to their current activity, then they don’t really know what they hope to get from it, and they can’t figure out what to do next. Those students who get the “story” can be engaged independent researchers, confidently analyzing results and charting the path of research into the future. Those who don’t get the story are dependent on me to tell them what to do, and they are relatively disengaged because their actions seem, to them, disjointed.
I think we can agree that we want our readers to be engaged.

I remember reading this paper. I was alternately incredulous and impressed that the authors managed to get such a plainly basic experiment into Nature. If I had done that experiment, I would have for sure sent the write-up to some lower tier journal, and it would have barely risen above the noise.
This is the genius of the authors: They recognized the potential of their work, and they sold it. They “told a story” and got their paper into the most prestigious journal around. For that brief moment, they won the game of academia.
The point is that science is not done in a vacuum. There is a community, there are people (with feelings), there are grants, there are grant applications, there is prestige, and there is competition. There are limited resources. If you want to win (a grant), you can’t just communicate the basic components of science: the details, the data, the analysis. You need to sell yourself and your project. You need people to understand how we’ve come to be where we are and how everything you’ve done and plan to do is the most logical, smart, and efficient path forward. You need to tell the story of your work and make your readers believe.
